# Problem to deploy war in glassfish

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, web-deployment

when i want to deploy my web application ( i make it with netbeans) in glassfish i have this error

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : tun__pm. Please see server.log for more details

The application is a RESTful web service , when i test it , netbeans deploy it and it work fine . But when i took the .war file and want to deploy it i have the error .

this is the log:

```
> [#|2011-04-30T19:50:05.229+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Invalid
> resource : tun__pm
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid
> resource : tun__pm    at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:539)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:468)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:154)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:213)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:220)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:166)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>   at
> org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
>   at
> org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
>   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
>   at
> javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>   at
> com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>   at
> javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>   at
> com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
> Caused by:
> com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException:
> Invalid resource : tun__pm    at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:272)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:253)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:243)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:537)
>   ... 74 more |#]
> 
> [#|2011-04-30T19:50:05.238+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Exception
> while preparing the app : Invalid
> resource : tun__pm
> com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException:
> Invalid resource : tun__pm    at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:272)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:253)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:243)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:537)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:468)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:154)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:213)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:220)
>   at
> org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:166)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>   at
> org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
>   at
> org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
>   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
>   at
> com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
>   at
> javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>   at
> com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>   at
> javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>   at
> com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>   at
> com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

i don't know what is `tun__pm` but tun is the name of the database connection in netbeans .Should i do something in glassfish for the database connection ? mysql is working ..

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue.
But anyways, had installed netbeans, which also installs glassfish along with it, if you select that option while installing.
In the services tab, if you right click on the Glassfish server, properties, the domain folder is : `C:\Users\\{username}\\.netbeans\7.1\config\GF3` 
and not `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1`

So if you start the default domain instance in netbeans and create any datasources , they actually store the connection pool and datasource info in the domain.xml in `C:\Users\\{username}\\.netbeans\7.1\config\GF3\domain1\config\domain.xml`.

**So solution is:** 
either copy

```
 <jdbc-connection-pool name="tunPool">...</jdbc-connection-pool>
 <jdbc-resource pool-name="tunPool" jndi-name="jdbc/tun"></jdbc-resource>
```

from your `C:\Users\\{username}\\.netbeans\7.1\config\GF3\domain1\config\domain.xml` to

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
```

OR

add your glassfish domain instance to the services tab in netbeans and create your datasource using it (in windows OS, before adding domain1 to netbeans, right click on netbeans and select 'Run as Administrator' for opening it or else netbeans fails to detect the presence of domain1)

Comment: I tried to use derby sample pool `jdbc/sample`... and I didn't see it on the `domain.xml`, but I see `jdbc/__default` that is essentially the same thing. so I changed and I works.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to create a JDBC resource in glassfish with the JNDI name of "tun_pm". This should resolve your lookup error.

Comment: I would recommend opening up the glassfish admin console and viewing what resournces have been exposed via JNDI and see if tun_pm is listed.  Its possible that instead of being called "tun_pm", it may be exposed by another name.

Comment: Why the hell is GlassFish molesting the names of resources declared in glassfish-resource.xml anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem while developing using **NetBeans 7.1.2 and Glassfish**, I don't know why but the data source and the related database service that I've been using disappear from time to time so it displays the next error while deploying:

`Grave: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : whateverDBcon__pm
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : whateverDBcon__pm`

**NetBeans 7.1.2 solution:** Maybe it's not the professional way but I have just created the same data source: `Configuration Files/persistence.xml` using the wizard you can find at the "Design" view. Just use the same JNDI name of the old one and it will create the JDBC service you needed.

cmutt78 had the key, thanks!